# Masters in Financial Engineering with C's and B's to PHD in Math

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics

I'm about to graduate with a degree in Financial Engineering from a top 15 program. I'm thinking about transitioning to a PHD in mathematics as I find it quite interesting. Unfortunately I've only managed to receive 3 B's and a C+ in my 4 math courses - no A's). (B's and A's in the non-pure-math courses like stats/programming/finance).

Would it be unreasonable to work for a couple of years then come back with these kind of grades, or would my chances of getting into a PHD program be untenable? Secondly would it even be worth it for me to pursue this path. Despite my interest in the field watching some of my classmates (admittedly they're graduates of places like Beijing) receive A's in some of these classes without as much effort makes me believe I may not even be capable and would just be wasting time applying.

Comment: Why do you want a PhD?  If you sufficiently far down the rankings (and I'm not sure "sufficiently far" is that far in this case), you could probably get a department that will admit you, but then you would need to have exceptional research results (by the standards of that department) to be able to get an academic position afterwards.  Not all PhDs are equal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question depends a little on where you're hoping to pursue a PhD, and I can only answer you if you plan to attend a PhD program in the U.S. To apply to a PhD program in the U.S., you'll almost definitely have to take the GRE, as well  as the GRE Subject Test in Math, both of which you can prepare for with practice tests. I  don't know how it works outside the U.S.

If you do reasonably well on the GRE and the GRE Subject Test and if you can get decent recommendations from a couple of your past professors, your chances of getting into a Math PhD program are decent, especially given your undergraduate program.

In my PhD program - when I got my PhD  - there were students at all sorts of levels of ability with all sorts of backgrounds and different levels of preparation in the beginning. That said, several did drop out in the first year. Those with more math preparation behind them, including non-pure math like statistics, had an easier time of it, so you have at least a little of that going for you.

All of us had a fighting chance, regardless of our backgrounds and levels of preparation,  as long as we consistently attended classes and did homework. By the time I graduated, it was very clear that those with a good work ethic, with self-confidence, and with a lot of tenacity were the ones who made it.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, actually I should have clarified that I'm currently a Masters student. I've already taken the basic GRE to get into my program but not the specific math GRE. My undergraduate degree was a double major, one of them being math.

Answer (score 1):

Your chances of admission to a Ph.D. program in mathematics will depend strongly on some factors that you haven't described in your question. I'm thinking particularly of (1) the content and level of the courses you  took and (2) the letters of recommendation from your professors.

The level of preparation that my department looks for in Ph.D. applicants is described on our web site at https://lsa.umich.edu/math/graduates/ph-d-programs/applying.html under the heading "General requirements for admission". I think other universities will also have descriptions of their expectations on their web sites.